# Why a jquery datepicker change days for months?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm working on MVC project, and using the jquery datepicker I have problems in the post.
I use a partial view which contains the text box and the jquery function. Like this:

```
 @model Nullable<System.DateTime>
<div class="row-fluid input-append">
    @if (Model.HasValue && Model.Value != DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model.Value), new { @class = "input-small date-picker",@readonly = true, style = "cursor:pointer; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;" })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ""), new { @class = "input-small date-picker", @readonly = true, style = "cursor:pointer; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;" })
    }
</div>

@{
    string name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    string id = name.Replace(".", "_");
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#@id').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        todayHighlight: true,
        clearBtn: true,
        forceParse: true,
        autoclose: true,
    });
</script>
```

When I format the datepicker to pick the date in days/months/years, and when I pick a date the format it's ok! I mean, I select 5th of august in the calendar, and the textbox shows 05/08/2013, but the problem arise when a click save because, in the controller, the value on the date is changed days to months! 
Thanks!

Comment: `mm/dd/yyyy` is the standard date format in the US. I would assume your problem is caused by part of your code thinking your locale is someplace it isn't. The database, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, wherefore i set "dd/mm/yy" in the dateFormat.. but don't work because in the controller i get a diferent format ("mm/dd/yy")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `web.config` add the following:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
</system.web>
```

It should change the default date parsing.

Comment: @Blazemonger - True... I just seen `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'` and thought "that's what I use - he must be in the UK!"