# DatePickerTextBox switching day and month

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

This is the line of code that declares my `DatePickerTextBox`:

```
<DatePickerTextBox Text="{Binding dateOfBirth, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" />
```

(notice the `StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy`)

When the `DatePickerTextBox` is empty with the placeholder `<Enter text here>`, and I write in it something like:

```
01-02-0003
```

...after clicking outside the `DatePickerTextBox`, the displayed text automatically changes to:

```
02-01-0003
```

(that is: automatically switching **month** and **day**)

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: As mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279831/why-a-jquery-datepicker-change-days-for-months) article, you might have to add the globalization culture to your app.config.

Comment: Define culture for your app. for example add this code to your app.config file: 
`<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
</system.web>`

Comment: or in your `UserControl` or a `Window` add this: `xml:lang="en-US"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its due to culture difference

Define the following xml namespace:

```
xmlns:gl="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Specify the CultureInfo relevant to you

```
<DatePickerTextBox Text="{Binding Path=dateOfBirth, 
                                  StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy,
                                  ConverterCulture={x:Static gl:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}" />
```

Comment: Than you so much, this seems to do the trick. But before marking it as the correct answer, I still have a little issue I don't seem to be able to solve: although in practice it works, the error list tells me that `The member "CurrentCulture" is not recognized or is not accessible.`. I have tried several things and the error sticks... although the compiler lets me rebuild the solution and run it. I'll try to dig a bit deeper to find a solution.

Comment: Well, as this answer suggests (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35017232/831138) the problem goes away if you target the .NET Framework 4.6 or higher. So I am marking it as the correct answer, but people should be aware that they'll encounter this problem if they use any Framework below v4.6.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wasn't aware.